# I have this error when I Invoke WCF Reference in ASP.NET CORE 6 As bellow

Tags: wcf, asp.net-core-6.0

'The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Bearer `realm="null",error="invalid_token",error_description="oauth.v2.InvalidAccessToken: Invalid access token`

```
        HttpResponseMessageProperty requestProp = new HttpResponseMessageProperty();
                    requestProp.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;

                    OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpResponseMessageProperty.Name] = requestProp;
                    requestProp.Headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + token.access_token;
                    requestProp.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/xml";

                    var result = await client.GetData(WaselAddressService.ItemChoiceType.NationalID, "50004541");
```

NET Core 6

Comment: according to the error message, the token you used can't bypass the validation of the service. could you pls share the tutorial you followed to write your code?